# What if my Android app required NFC permission but actually haven't used it?

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

I have packed and uploaded my Android app to Google Play, and received multiple warnings, like android.permissions.NFC would result in user not upgrading to this version...So, my problem is actually I haven't used any function with NFC, it's just a mistake. What would happen if I just release this version? Would google play just stop no-NFC devices from upgrading?

Comment: Remove the permission and upload the new apk since it was a mistake that you added it. You definitely don't want any paranoid users spotting the NFC permission then not discovering any noticeable NFC features and suspecting something fishy with your app.

Answer (score 0):

You should never ask for permissions you don't use. You will reduce your installs from security conscious users, and it is misleading.